# Collect Elasticsearch Access Log

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I want to collect elasticsearch access logs, but the official method is not free. Is there an open source and free method that can meet my situation? I am using es7

Answer (score 0):

if you mean query or indexing log.maybe the easy way is to setup an nginx proxy since Elasticsearch query based on http.so we can log the query in nginx access log.
another way maybe use Elasticsearch self slow log?I not sure if that is OK.

Comment: First of all, thank you. Slow log may not be a good solution. Nginx proxy and Shield plugin are currently two methods under consideration, but I need to confirm whether the plugin is suitable for use in es7.

Comment: can you paste the plugin link here.I wish to do some research

Comment: Okay, if you are also using the new version of es, the Shield Plugin seems to have become part of X-Pack. The link to the plugin is https://www.elastic.co/cn/downloads/shield

Comment: I find xpack.but I can't find the method about access logs.can you give a name about that function

Comment: In the newer version, the official one is called the audit log, but it is chargeable, hope it will help you